# How do i catch system Lock and Unlock events in Python or PyQt4 under RHEL

Tags: python, linux, pyqt

I have an application developed in Python 2.6 and PyQt4 under windows. its working fine over there.

Now we are making it a multiplatform application to support under Linux (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6).

In the application we are updating database based on system Lock and Unlock events. ie., when a system is locked by user (win Key + L under windows) a function will run and update the database as required. Same when user unlock also a function will run.

Can any one suggest an approach to catch Lock and Unlock events in linux (REHL)

Comment: You should explain more clearly what you mean by "system Lock and Unlock events" and exactly how they are used within your application.

Comment: added more info as suggested. System "Lock and unlock events" mean when ever user locks and unlocks there workstation.